# Aligning the new navbar

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, top-bar

I might be slightly neurotic when it comes to pretty alignment in web design, posters, cutlery, town hall tiles, YOU NAME IT, but I thought that the new Stack Overflow navbar could use some small refinements as well.

Below is a quick sketch-up. The top shows what the navbar looks like now, and below is an alignment suggestion. The orange bar when the Questions view is active, aligns with the left border of content. The search bar aligns with the right border. Stack Overflow's logo should also move slightly to the right to decrease the space between the tabs and the logo - this would mean increasing its padding so the logo itself is still neatly aligned to the content.

The 'charms bar'/personal notifications can also be updated. Note that the actual alignment would be on their hover states, with a darker background which are a bit wider than the icons themselves. Basically it comes down to fitting inside the width of Stack Overflow's sidebar.

[image: Nav mockup]

I am curious to see if anyone is also more fond of aligned behaviour like this, or if I'm going over the top with my ideas here.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Will *TRIGGERED*

Comment: It's centered; can't be done. Unless you find a way to snap to it when you happen to be near that edge—which depends on your window real estate.

Comment: It's because you have a gold badge. People without gold badge don't have this issue.

Comment: @Knu I don't understand what you mean by 'can't be done', or which edge you are targeting. In the widest version of the website, it should be very well possible to do this with a bit of CSS.

Comment: Re: avatar and sidebar alignment - that right section is fluid, which means width of it depends on many aspects: rep, badges, role (normal user vs mod) etc.. so in some cases you may see avatar aligned to sidebar. in other cases this whole section can be wider than sidebar.. or narrower...

Comment: Re: main nav & content alignment - this is also dependent on what page you are on, if you scrolled down or not and so on.. if we move everything to right just to align nav with content, we would notice misalignment in other places..